# copy dropdown field selection into a hidden text field

Tags: jquery, forms, function, textfield

I know this has been covered before, but i can't find exactly what i need....

to put things short, i need to copy the selected option from a dropdown field to a text box. And i have this code to do it:

```
$(function(){
    $('#font').bind('change', function(){
        $('#input').val($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

BUT, the page loads with a pre-selected option in the drop-down field, which means that people don't necessarily need to select an option. How can i get the field with id #input to show the option from the drop down menu #font even if the user does not engage and select a different option?

Miro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on page load

```
$(function(){
    //this first line loads the pre-selected value into the text box
    $('#input').val($('#font option:selected').val());
    //still want to bind the change event
    $('#font').bind('change', function(){
        $('#input').val($('#font option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8CG/5/

check out the fiddle, thanks to answer by @MetalFrog.

Comment: thanks thats great! just one question... Instead of returning the value in the text filed, is it possible to return the text? What i mean is that the value is a url address, while the text just says Ariel for example. I replaced the last .val()) with text.(() but this only works when the page loads. Once i change the selection, all of the options display in the text field, one after another.

Comment: Yes you have to specify to only update the selected value of the drop down. OK will update the answer, you need `option:selected` in the function that is bound to the click event.

Comment: Thanks. I've just realised there is a more simple solution to this... just pre-fill the input field with the default value of the drop-down...

Answer (score 2):

Just trigger a change on your select during the page load.

```
$(function(){        
    $('#font').change( function(){
        $('#input').val( $(this).val() );
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MetalFrog/Us8CG/

Answer (score 1):

Save the value into `#input` when the DOM is ready, then set up the `change` event handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('#input').val($('#font').val());
    $('#font').bind('change', function(){
        $('#input').val($(this).val());
    });
});​
```